# How to make an object into text in js

Tags: javascript, object

Here is a js object that represents the file system in the command line os project I'm working on:

```
var obj = {
        "1": {
            "hi": "hi"
        }, 
        "2": {
            "bye": "bye"
         }
    };
var currentDir = obj["1"]["hi"];
console.log(currentDir);
```

When I run this, I get

```
"hi"
```

How do I get this to appear as

```
/1/hi/
```

I need to get the "file path" of the currently select object.

Comment: Your code logs `"hi"` when I run it, not `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: THat doesn't make any sense.  Javascript does not record which properties refer to a value.

Comment: It works for me, but try `obj[1].hi`

Comment: So, what *exactly* are you trying to do?  What's the issue here?

Comment: @Chase Welcome to StackOverflow. It's not very clear what you're trying to do, because **it doesn't seem like you have an understanding of the language constructs** that you're using. I recommend doing some reading about javascript objects and arrays, and the accessors for each. When you have a better understanding, come back and revise your question.

Comment: I'm sorry this i s poor wording on my part, I need to "get the file path" of the object

Comment: @Chase: That is fundamentally impossible.  The same string can be referenced by multiple objects.  You need to re-think your design.

Comment: @Chase, as you're entering `"1"` and `"hi"` manually, why can't you just do `"1" + "/" + "hi" + "/"`?

Comment: Unclear.. something like this; http://jsfiddle.net/WmSKL/ ?

Comment: Don't you already know the path when you address the object? do something like `console.log(firstIndex + '/' + secondIndex + '/ + obj[firstIndex][secondIndex]);`

Comment: that's the idea. I don't know how to split the currentDir into those parts.

Comment: @Chase: You can't.  Where are `"1"` and `"hi"` coming from?  Once you do `obj["1"]`, you can't go back and get the key (`"1"`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make some kind of lookup function

```
var lookup = (function (o) {
    return function lookup() {
        var i, e = o, s = '';
        for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
            s += '/' + arguments[i];
            if (!e.hasOwnProperty(arguments[i]))
                throw "PathNotFoundError: " + s;
            e = e[arguments[i]];
        }
        return {path: s, value: e};
    }
}(obj));
```

And using it

```
console.log(lookup('1', 'hi').path); // "/1/hi"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns `"hi"` So does `var currentDir = obj[1].hi;`

Comment: I need to get the path of objects to the current object

Answer (score 0):

You already know the path when you access your object. do something like this:

`console.log(firstIndex + '/' + secondIndex + '/ + obj[firstIndex][secondIndex]);`

you can use this in `for` loops, `each` loops `while` etc.. or by direct access like your example.