# Javascript: build multidimensional Array programmatically

Tags: javascript, json

My goal is to be able to keep track of my position/depth in a JSON tree by adding elements to an Array and then access nested nodes in the JSON utilizing this Array. By now say the Array `foo` it has one element:

```
foo = ["customers"]
```

so that element would act as a reference for a JSON children, say:

```
jsonTree["customers"]
```

where jsonTree is something like:

```
{
"customers":{
  "name": "J. Goldsmith",
  "orders": [{
    "order": "1",
    "order": "2"
  }]
 }
}
```

Then `foo` eventually varies its size and become

```
foo = ["customers","orders"]
```

So the JSON reference would become

```
jsonTree["customers"]["orders"]
```

Now say that `customers.orders` can become `customers.orders.order.date.etc.etc`... Is there any way to build the `jsonTree` reference programmatically with N dimensions based on the N elements of `foo` Array?

*Some examples:*

I have `["John","Williams"]` -> i want to build `composer["John"]["Williams"]`
["Erich","Wolfgang","Korngold"] -> i want to build `composer["Erich"]["Wolfgang"]["Korngold"]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Multidimensional Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808926/javascript-multidimensional-arrays)...but I love the music references!  JS does not do multidimensional arrays.

Comment: Would you also explain what you intend to do with this? It seems like a helper construct of some sort, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Do you want to create `jsonTree` or just select a value?  Can't you just use a loop?  `var ref = jsonTree; for(var i in foo){ if(foo.hasOwnProperty(i)){ ref = ref[foo[i]]; }}`

Comment: @DerekHenderson: What do you mean by "JS does not do multidimensional arrays"?  Yes it does.  `var multi = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];`

Comment: Additionally, your sample object is not syntactically valid. Please set up a working sample on jsFiddle that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @RocketHazmat That's not a multi-dimensional array. That's an array of arrays.

Comment: @Tomalak: Umm, what's the difference?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, quoting directly from the accepted answer to the question I cited as a duplicate:  "JavaScript does not have multidimensional arrays, but arrays of arrays, which can be used in a similar way."

Comment: @DerekHenderson: That doesn't really help.  Are you trying to say that a multi-dimensional array and an array of arrays are two different things?!  If so, what's the difference?  I'm so confused.

Comment: @RocketHazmat An array of arrays has one dimension, that's the difference. Some of its members might be other one-dimensional arrays, but they don't have to be. It's a nested data structure. A multi-dimensional array is uniform. You can have an array of arrays that *behaves like* a multi-dimensional array, but that's neither the only way to build it nor is it enforced in any way.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, to be honest, I wasn't really sure either, but my friend Google revealed the following to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-is-differences-between-multidimensional-array-and-array-of-arrays-in-c. Although that question is specifically about C, the answers suffice for JS.

Comment: @Tomalak: So, a multi-dimensional array is an array of arrays where the dimensions are enforced?  I never knew a structure like that existed!  Guess that's what I get for coming from a PHP/JavaScript background.  I've always used the term "multi-dimensional array" to describe a data-structure like: `var multi = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];`.  :-) I guess there's nothing stopping you from doing `var multi = ['a',[1,2,3],'b',[4,5,6],'c',[7,8,9,10]];` :-P

Comment: @Rocket: That's the point. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: Well, I learned something new today! :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is some sort of lookup function like that I [**describe here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17323348/1615483), except modified slightly to take an *Array* instead of multiple arguments

```
function generateLookupFunction(o) {
    return function lookup(arr) {
        var i, e = o;
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            if (!e.hasOwnProperty(arr[i]))
                throw "PathNotFoundError: " + arr.slice(0, i + 1).join('/');
            e = e[arr[i]];
        }
        return e;
    };
}
```

Then

```
var lookup = generateLookupFunction(jsonTree),
    foo = ["customers","orders"];
lookup(foo);
/*[{
    "order": "1",
    "order": "2"
}] */
```